# Need to convert bytes to GB, MB, KB in normal decimal format

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have the given code below for converting bytes to the corresponding values:

```
for OUTPUT in $(find $IP_DIR -maxdepth 1 | awk 'NR>1')
do
    case $RETURNSIZE in
        "gb") FS=`du -b $OUTPUT | awk {'print $1'}`
              FS=`echo $FS | awk '{ byte =$1 /1024/1024**2 ; print byte " GB" }'`
              echo $OUTPUT "|" $FS;;
        "mb") FS=`du -b $OUTPUT | awk {'print $1'}`
              FS=`echo $FS | awk '{ byte =$1 /1024/1024 ; print byte " MB" }'`
              echo $OUTPUT "|" $FS;;
        "kb") FS=`du -b $OUTPUT | awk {'print $1'}`
              FS=`echo $FS | awk '{ byte =$1 /1024 ; print byte " KB" }'`
              echo $OUTPUT "|" $FS;;
        "b")  FS=`du -b $OUTPUT | awk {'print $1'}`
              echo $OUTPUT "|" $FS "B";;
    esac
    

OUTPUT

/home/work/exten.sh | 3.53903e-07 GB
/home/work/e.txt | 0 GB
/home/work/t.txt | 0 GB
/home/worktest | 9.53674e-07 GB
/home/work/s.txt | 3.23169e-07 GB
```

The logic seems to be perfectly working but when the case comes to `gb (RETURNSIZE)`, the result is in exponential format.

But I am looking for the result in normal decimal format.

Comment: Since you tagged your question with `linux`: what's wrong with `du -Sh`?

Comment: @SatoKatsura I cannot use that flag because my requirement is to get the  output i.e. the size in actual figures. And "-h" flag gives me the values rounded off.

Comment: Ok.  Then you could set `OFMT`.  Or use `printf()` instead of `print`.

Comment: Note this GB calculation is the "Gigibyte" method (how system memory is calculated, all 1024's no 1000s). As such the "GB" above is the wrong label, and should be "GiB".  See http://hexus.net/tech/tech-explained/storage/1376-gigabytes-gibibytes-what-need-know/

Answer (score 58):

Since this is Linux I'm surprised no-one mentioned the `numfmt` command:

> numfmt - Convert numbers from/to human-readable strings

```
>>numfmt --to iec --format "%8.4f" 599511627776
558.3388G
```

Comment: example to convert the first column from stdout :  `echo -e "1024 1048576\n1048576 1024 " | numfmt --to iec`

Comment: This also works the other way around like `numfmt --from=auto 10Gi` which is useful for parsing user input.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't tested, but I think it has something to do with you loading the bc mathlib with `bc -l`.

Try changing the `awk` calculation piece for GB to:

`awk '{ byte =$1 /1024/1024/1024; print byte " GB" }'`

Note: `1024/1024**2` is equivalent to `1024/1024/1024` in `awk`.

Comment: Sorry by mistake I had pasted the trail code there earlier. Now I have edited them. I have tried this possibility earlier itself. I was still getting the values in exponential form. 
Along with this "1 GB = 1073741824 B = 1048576 MB"

Comment: This is nice and neat. The "GB vs "GiB" comment I made in the accepted answer, also applies here.

Answer (score 3):

```
> printf "1GiB\\nMB" | units
Currency exchange rates from finance.yahoo.com on 2017-10-31 
3047 units, 109 prefixes, 109 nonlinear units

You have: You want:     * 1073.7418
        / 0.00093132257
You have:
```

or

```
> echo $((1024*1024*1024))
1073741824
>
```

See also: [man 7 units](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/units.7.html)

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `bc` instead of `awk`?
Like:

```
$ a=2342341234534634653453452342
$ echo "scale=2; $a/1024/1024" | bc -l
2233830675634989407971.81
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a small cli for this.

https://github.com/gonejack/hsize

```
> hsize 123 45678
123 => 123B
45678 => 44.61KB
```

```
> echo 19129219219129119 | hsize
19129219219129119 => 16.99PB
```