# Format size in bytes as human readable

Tags: utilities

Is there a standard command that will format a simple value (size in bytes) as a human readable format (similar to the `-h` switch on `du`, `ls`, ...)?

eg.

```
echo 1852 | format       # should print 1.9K
echo 3145728000 | format # should print 3.0G
```

Comment: should that be in the short (k=1^3) or long (k=2^10) scale?

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44040/5132 again, similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346902/5132 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `numfmt` tool, which can covert raw strings to known math standards, e.g.

```
 echo 3145728000 | numfmt --to=iec
 3.0G
```

The tool is part of the GNU coreutils family.

Comment: `numfmt` isn’t a standard command.

Comment: Agreed, will wait for a confirmation to see if OP doesn't have GNU coreutils

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I was able to find `numfmt` on Arch/Ubuntu.